# How to query data expiration time in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

In my Database I have products that i saved with the expiration timestamp in the format  eg. **2018-22-08**. Please how do I select all products that will expire in less than 4 days.

I have tried

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE expiration_timestamp = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 4 DAY)
```

Comment: what did using that inside phpmyadmin show you or echoing / var_dump'ing the query?

Comment: Do you have `expiration_timestamp` values that are earlier than today (that also need to be filtered out)? If so, I might suggest `BETWEEN`. By the way, `expiration_timestamp` is a suboptimally named column. Don't you agree that `expiration_date` makes better sense for you and future developers who may need to interact with your code/db?  I get the sense that you haven't toiled very long before posting a question -- this seems very basic. (What does `=` do?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use less than operator

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE expiration_timestamp <  DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 4 DAY)
```